# To Unfurl Links as Images in Slack

Tags: python, slack

I have followed the steps as suggested in the Slack API’s [Unfurling links in messages](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-link-unfurling#setup):

Steps Completed:

1. Subscribe to the right events
2. Register Domain names

However while handling event deliveries, in the event type the link for the image is being identified as a “message” and not “link-shared” as mentioned in the post. So unfurling the link into an image is not happening.

What could be the problem? What am I missing?

Comment: Could you add an example of the domain name you registered and a sample message that isn't being received as a `link_shared` event?

Comment: Domain name is 10ay.online.tableau.com and the message is event": {
        "type": "message",
        "user": "UARJZ73R9",
        "text": "<https://10ay.online.tableau.com/t/abcd.png>",
        "bot_id": "BASPAAD71",
        "ts": "1528921660.000537",
        "channel": "DAR1V5V6C",
        "event_ts": "1528921660.000537",
        "channel_type": "im"
    }

Comment: Slack won't unfurl links that are missing a protocol. Try sending the link as `http://10ay.online.tableau.com/t/abcd.png` and see if that works. From the docs: `When users mention links to one of your domains, it must be fully qualified with a protocol (http:// or https://). Slack will not unfurl decidedly ambiguous domain and URL mentions.`

Comment: Thanks Adil B. I tried adding a fully qualified URL with protocol, however as soon as I save the changes, the protocol is stripped off automatically and what remains is just this - 10ay.online.tableau.com.

Comment: how about in the test message you're sending - does adding `https://` to the link in your Slack message change anything?

Comment: Tried that too, no luck.